# Given a property, how to find to which object the property belongs?

Tags: javascript, properties

I've got a few DOM elements, say text-field input A, B, C, and all of them have the property of 'onclick'. How do I find to which object a particular 'onclick' belongs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You're probably trying to find the element that triggered an event handler.</strike>

If so, use the `this` keyword.

### EDIT

Apparently, you have an inline event handler as a string, and you're trying to find the element that the handler was attached to, from the string.

This is completely impossible.

A string is just a string.  Just because your string happens to contain Javascript code, and happens to be assigned to a property on an object, doesn't make it any different from any other string;  Javascript does not track parent references in objects.

Instead, you should bind an anonymous function as an event handler using [jQuery](http://jquery.com).
(Or, if you really don't want to use jQuery, [`addEventListener` / `attachEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:element.addEventListener))

Comment: yes! I'm trying to find the element that triggered an event handler. I actually tried this, but it returns undefined. here's my code:

var oc_property = document.forms[0].realname.onclick;
console.log("onclick's element: " + oc_property.this);

Comment: Ha, ha, clueless. Also, jQuery? Ugh. :P

Comment: @Delan:‌‌‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‍ ‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‍What?

Comment: Hi SLaks, how to find the element if I use addEventListener like the following:

document.forms[0].realname.addEventListener('click', hello, true);

Comment: You can add separate, identical functions (or wrapper functions) and make a property on each function object.  Note that if you set the property to the DOM element, you'll get a memory leak in IE6.  Use its name or ID instead.